# Is it possible to have nullmailer resolve recipient's MX servers like sendmail does?

Tags: debian, email, sendmail, debian-buster

I installed `nullmailer` on a Debian 10 VPS.

```
root@:~# cat /etc/nullmailer/remotes
hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com
```

- `echo "Subject: test" | sendmail -v me@hotmail.com` works, I receive the e-mail.
- `echo "Subject: test" | sendmail -v me@example.com` doesn't work, saying:

  > smtp: Failed: 550 5.5.0 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable. [DM6NAM12FT063.eop-nam12.prod.protection.outlook.com]

As far as I understand, for `example.com` to work, I have to resolve it's MX record and put the value into `/etc/nullmailer/remotes`.

Sendmail seems to handle that automatically.

- Can `nullmailer` do that as well?
- If not, what is a lightweight yet capable alternative (`msmtp`, `swaks`)?
- Or should I have a wrapper script doing `dig` first, saving to `/etc/nullmailer/remotes`, and only then calling `nullmailer`?

Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can nullmailer do that as well?

No. It is a "relay-only" MTA, i.e. it always relies on another full-featured SMTP relay server (a "smarthost") to handle the actual delivery. (Hence the "null" name.)

Really, that's kind of *the whole point* of using nullmailer or msmtp or similar tools.

> If not, what is a lightweight yet capable alternative

If you define 'lightweight' as in "no permanent daemon processes running", then Exim can do the job – it tries to deliver mail in foreground by default (i.e. right in the same `sendmail` process), and if that fails, you can use a cronjob to process queued mail.

Otherwise, OpenSMTPd would be my choice, followed by Postfix. While they run as daemons, they don't really consume a noticeable amount of resources and the outgoing-only config file can be tiny.

> Or should I have a wrapper script doing dig first, saving to /etc/nullmailer/remotes, and only then calling nullmailer?

Only if your script implements locking (single instance). Editing global configuration can go really wrong if you allow it to make multiple deliveries simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, accepting it because I really like it, although I ended up taking the `/etc/nullmailer/remotes` route as it's the easiest for me right now (there's one recipient on that system only)